# Understanding an implied politic news article

Tags: reading-comprehension

> It had once been a transatlantic art scandal -- or at least various actors of questionable intent would have you believe it was.

It's [the CNN article](https://edition.cnn.com/2021/01/21/politics/winston-churchill-bust-oval-office/index.html) about a bust of Churchill in the Oval Office. I understand the argument about the bust and the article but I don't the specific sentence.

Why had it been an 'art' scandal and what does 'questionable intent' mean? Is it about movies of Churchill like Darkest Hour and their glamorization?

Comment: No, it is not about movies. It is about CNN's dislike for certain politicians and their positions. When you read (American) news, be aware that this is often the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m assuming that people didn’t like that the bust was their for some reason. Either they disliked Churchill or disliked the bust being there for patriotic reasons. The article is suggesting that the people claiming this are doing it not because they are genuinely upset that it is there, but for some unknown, but immoral or unethical reason. Someone with *questionable intent* is likely a **bad actor**, someone who is not speaking in good faith; as in, they’re willing to lie and obfuscate to get their way, usually to their own benefit in terms of money or power.

*Note: “actor” is a word to watch out for; it usually means someone who plays parts in movies, but here it just means “person who acts”, meaning “does stuff”.*

Comment: Understanding 'actor' as a 'movie actor' was the missed point. Thanks. Does 'art' mean 'scheme' or is there any real 'artistic' problem which I miss more?